# how to make modifications in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sorting

i have a gridview table like this...

```
<div>

  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AllowSorting="true" 
    OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" >
  </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

i am populating the gridview with 2 arraylists like following

```
DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");


            taskTable.Columns.Add("File Name");

            taskTable.Columns.Add("Failure Count");

            for (int i = 0; i < namesOfFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow tableRow = taskTable.NewRow();
                tableRow["File Name"] = namesOfFiles[i];
                tableRow["Failure Count"] = buFailureCount[i];
                taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
            }
            Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;

           GridView1.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
           GridView1.DataBind();
```

so now when i run this i dont see anything on the screen unless i put the autogenerate column property as true....

is there a way i can get template fields coz i know many ways to modify data in gridview then, or  a way for these columns to be aligned  in my code behind.. as now the header and the items are stuck on the left margin...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily get template fields by using the `BoundField` element.  There also exists `ItemTemplate` elements for greater control of the grid view.  [MSDN's tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) should give you all you need to know.

Effectively your code will come out something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="HireDate" SortExpression="HireDate" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

To style your grid view you'll want to take a look at the [`<RowStyle />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx) element.